# SQL like - select strings that contain unspecified characters

Tags: sql, regex, sql-like

First of all, apologies if this is a duplicate question. I've done my best to search but was unsuccessful, and I couldn't even properly word my question in terms of keywords!

One of my tables has a column `Name (nvarchar)`. I want to find out which rows contain special characters **without** explicitly listing those characters. "Special" characters in my case means anything not in:

```
a-z A-Z 0-9 _ @ . , ( ) % + -
```

So for example:

```
Row 1: 'asdf Asdf 0123'
Row 2: 'asdf (Asdf) 012/3'
Row 3: 'zxcv [234]'
Row 4: 'asdf #0123'
```

I want to select rows 2, 3 and 4.

The easiest way is to include the characters I don't want, for example square brackets and slash:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Name LIKE '%[\]\[/]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

This returns rows 2 and 3, or if I use NOT LIKE, rows 1 and 4. However, I also want to find other characters which I may not have thought of (such as the #). Listing the characters that ARE wanted -

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9_@. ,()%+-]%'
```

doesn't work either, as it returns 0 results since all rows contain at least 1 of those characters.

Is there a way to restrict the latter LIKE statement not to match **any** string that contains my desired characters, but rather strings that contain **only** the desired characters and nothing else?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server, but I think this shouldn't be DBMS-dependent. Also, I think I just found a solution which I'll post if correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can do:

```
WHERE Name REGEX '[^-a-zA-Z0-9.,()%+]'
```

Not sure if the same REGEX operator exists in SQL Server, but it probably has something similar.

Comment: Just did `WHERE Name LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9_@. ,()%+-]%'` as per this page http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp . I had already seen - and tried - this prior to asking this question but for some reason hadn't gotten it right. Either way, this is pretty much what I was looking for so thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tblWHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',col) >1`

Should return the rows that have non alpha numeric characters. You may need to alter the regex for your specific needs.

```
use tempdb
create table tbl ( col varchar(40) NULL)

insert into tbl VALUES ('lowercase')
insert into tbl VALUES ('UPPER')
insert into tbl VALUES ('0123')
insert into tbl VALUES ('special characters & ^')
insert into tbl VALUES ('special characters ! \/')
insert into tbl VALUES ('special characters _ + = ')
insert into tbl VALUES (NULL)

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%',col) >1

drop table tbl
```

Comment: I think this is unnecessarily complex; I used LIKE and the ^ wildcard as shown here http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp . Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I'd check out the performance of `LIKE` vs `PATINDEX` - its not more complex than a `like` really, just a function call instead of a predicate. I've read mixed results about the relative performance of the two methods, one of them might give you faster results...

Comment: I meant longer and more difficult to write/understand :) The script needs to be shared with others who will use it just once, so my primary concern is simplicity/readability, not performance.